# Display draft posts on single pages

Tags: posts, draft

I made my published post as draft post. It is not showing it in the website blog, but, when i use its URL it is showing "Error 404 - Not Found". but what i want is to show the content of draft post when the URL is given in the browser.

Comment: Please be **specific** and do **not** change the question and scope of the question to fit your needs after someone has answered your originally posted question. This is not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change into the code, by default wordpress shows only post which are published. In your case you need to change the

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'draft')
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

for more info you can look into this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

Another thing you can alter your current query using query post like `query_posts(&post_status=draft)`

Comment: This won't work, your main query **will** still 404 regardless. And **never ever** use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object which break all plugins anf functions that relies on the main query object

Comment: Yes, @PieterGoosen `query_post` is never recommend, that's why I not explain this. :)

Comment: Yes, @PieterGoosen your ans is exact ans, I just try to lead him into the direction. :)

Comment: sorry, but I have mentioned the same requirement in the question.